# modifying first column with a sub seperator

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk

Suppose I have a  a text file:

```
aaa-123;bread;apple;banana
aaa-123;bread;apple;banana
aaa-123;bread;apple;banana
bbb-123;bread;apple;banana
bbb-1234;bread;app-le;banana
bbb-222;bread;apple;banana
```

i need to delete between - and ; on first column via awk
expected result:

```
aaa;bread;apple;banana
aaa;bread;apple;banana
aaa;bread;apple;banana
bbb;bread;apple;banana
bbb;bread;app-le;banana
bbb;bread;apple;banana
```

Comment: What did your attempts and research tell you?

Comment: Pattern unclear, your "expected output" is different from what you tell us.

Comment: Sorry its my bad
awk seperator is ';' i want to modify only first column, and need to delete after '-' character.

Comment: Read about `sub()` under [String Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) in the GNU awk manual. Make sure you set OFS to ";"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with `awk` and using `split()` function:

```
awk -v FS=';' 'split($1,a,/-/) {$1=a[1];print $1, $2, $3, $4}' OFS=';' file
aaa;bread;apple;banana
aaa;bread;apple;banana
aaa;bread;apple;banana
bbb;bread;apple;banana
bbb;bread;app-le;banana
bbb;bread;apple;banana
```

Comment: Thanks Carlos thats what i exactly need.

Comment: That's the wrong way to do this with awk. It's lengthy, unnecessarily hard-coding the fields, and would delete any lines where the first field doesn't contain `-`. Also, setting FS and OFS to the same literal char separately, especially assigning one before and one after the script, just obfuscates the code and introduces duplication.

Comment: Yes, now I see you are right: I admire your experimented observations about `awk`, 1+ for your solution and I remove my code. Thanks, Ed.

Answer (score 3):

This will work using any awk in any shell on every Unix box no matter which fields contain `-`s and whether the first field has one or not:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} {sub(/-.*/,"",$1)} 1' file
aaa;bread;apple;banana
aaa;bread;apple;banana
aaa;bread;apple;banana
bbb;bread;apple;banana
bbb;bread;app-le;banana
bbb;bread;apple;banana
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `sed` in non-greedy (shortest possible) match:

```
sed 's/-[^;]*;/;/' infile
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{gsub(/-[0-9]*/,"",$1);print }' filename

 sed 's/-[0-9]*//g' filename
```

Python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import re 
m=re.compile(r'-[0-9]*')
k=open('filename','r')
for i in k:
    m=re.sub(o,"",i)
    print m.strip()
```

output

```
aaa;bread;apple;banana
aaa;bread;apple;banana
aaa;bread;apple;banana
bbb;bread;apple;banana
bbb;bread;apple;banana
bbb;bread;apple;banana
```